# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: waiwai933]
[image: Matt]
[image: WendiKidd]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Please also welcome J.R. to the moderation team! He has graciously volunteered to help out with the increased workload after waiwai933 had to scale back a bit due to other commitments.

[image: J.R.]

Comment: Brava Anna! and Bravo, @J.R. Two Daniels come to judgment.

Comment: @J.R., sometimes what is right is *very* right, and I'm with you, congratulations! I hope to see you like a moderator on EL&U, too, since you are the only one who really understand the difference between ELL and that SE-site.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Let's see how I handle moderator duties here before campaigning for anything else :^)

Comment: @J.R. your untiring attitude is noteworthy. I see this as the best step as you are now one of the key persons.

Comment: @MaulikV - I'm happy to have you on the moderation team. For one, it's been fun working with you over the past few years. For another, it'll be nice to have someone on the other side of the globe who can be awake while Wendi and I are sleeping over in this hemisphere!

Comment: trust me, I **actually** thought about the timezone first! :) @J.R.