# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language Learners's [first moderator election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: J.R.] [image: WendiKidd] [image: Maulik V]

They'll be joining (or rejoining) [the moderator list](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering!

Please also thank the outgoing [Moderators *Pro Tempore*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) who have done so much to make this site the success that it is.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6585248951304192/0).

Comment: I'm speechless as 'thank you all' is not enough. I'm touched. And, I **commit** to be faithful and contributing to this loveliest website that recognized my efforts and gave me the responsibility. Love you!

Comment: A hearty "well done!" to our assorted bundle of moderators. Just one question - how do you pronounce @MaulikV - 'mow-lick', or 'more-lick'?

Comment: The former one! And thanks, sir! @DamienH

Comment: @Catija The goal was to do it yesterday or today - really hoping to still do it today, just need to hammer out one tiny detail regarding the big fancypants announcement we'll be making with it.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks so much for keeping us in the loop! Can't wait to get the official notice :D

Answer (score 16):

First I'd like to thank our pro tempore crew for sustaining a fabulous site for learners while their assistance was crucial for the site. **[WendiKidd](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/289/wendikidd)**, **[Matt](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/307/matt)**, **[waiwai933](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33/waiwai933)** and especially **[J.R.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r)**.

And now . . .

[image: CONGRATS!]   [image]

To our new mod crew:

- **J.R.**: The monument of moderation and personability, and being for ELL when ELL needed him. I congratulate him for standing up for us once again, and baring a responsibility that'd be tiresome for most of us.
- **MaulikV**: Someone with a lot of passion for ELL; who never ceases to share his knowledge and accept his mistakes when others correct him. I would like to see him with a diamond, but I wouldn't like to see his contributions slow down. :)
- **WendiKidd**: One of the few people in ELL that really understood what ELL's problems are, what ELLers need and what they should do. Although the decisions she made with our meta community hardly kept consistently rolling out in the main site, I'd still love to see and hear more from her.

Comment: I want to thank the other seven candidates you haven't named here. I think it was healthy for the site to have a good number of worthy candidates to choose from, and I'm thankful they stepped up to the plate and ran in this election. Collectively, those candidates have been indispensable to ELL in the past few months: flagging troublesome posts, leaving helpful comments, making improvements via edits, etc. I hope all of those runners-up will continue to play their vital role in keeping the site running smoothly and making the job of moderation less tedious and more manageable. Thanks to all!

Comment: Thank you so very much. Yes, I respect the 'diamond', and will prove myself worth having it.

Answer (score 5):

With this result, ELL has set an example where a non-native speaker is elected as a moderator. Yes, I take all the advice and suggestions in a positive way, and will prove myself to be an asset to this site. To J.R. and Wendikidd - I'll try my level best to be the best companion here. And, never feel hesitated if you need my help or contribution in anything.

As I said, 'thanks to all' is not enough. But still, heartfelt thanks to all who put faith in me and voted for me. This is the **biggest day** of my life and the credit goes to all of you. Love you all!

### Feel like a

[image]

Comment: Congrats Sir for officially becoming the voice of non-native speakers on this wonderful platform! We always need you for improving our second language- English. :)

Comment: Yes, Ruchir. Thanks for your constant support. I'll never let you down! :)

Comment: Congrats Maulik sir, I am really happy to see a diamond next to your name. As a non-native speaker, I always need your help in this site.

Comment: Thanks @RamyaS. I'm always there (especially for non-natives). Just a little note: 'the diamond' and 'on this site'. The lesson begins ... :)

Comment: :) Learning started...

Comment: Wow, a rebus in your acceptance speech. Nice :^)

Comment: Congrats! I have to add though, that you've already proven yourself to be an asset to ELL.

Comment: Thank you Colleen. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Congrats Maulik, and welcome to the team! Please don't hesitate to reach out to @J.R. and I in the mod room if you have questions; I know it was a bit of an overwhelming experience to get used to the mod tools/responsibilities, and we're here to help onboard you :)

Comment: ELU has more than one moderator who is not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Fabulous! :) Now, as bosses may say, "get back to work!" :D Anyways, we have much to do to ensure ELL is ready for graduation. I started out with [helping users to find out how to write titles](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question) and [starting the title cleanup act](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28833/title-clean-up-phase-3-faq-ready). I wonder if you could lend me a hand: Was wondering if you'd mind featuring the FAQ and participating in the event? Thank you. (If that isn't possible, could one of the crew be present?)

Comment: I hate to be the dissenting voice, but - let's not attribute your election _non-native speaker_ status. You were elected _not just_ because you're a non-native speaker, but because of your contributions which have made you an invaluable asset to the site - and **that's** what you should be proud of.

Comment: @WendiKidd thanks and same to you. True, I'm hooked up with a lot of articles' links, suggestions, notifications in my 'mod' tab. Please bear with me...it'll take some time to get accustomed. Thanks for your support. I'll definitely reach out to you guys in case I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to all of the three new moderators! :) Personally I'm very happy that my favorite candidates (that I had voted for) have been elected as Moderators.

@MaulikV, a non-native speaker (From my country ;-)), has been elected as a moderator in ELL. This happened only because of your excellent contribution to this site.

I had an experience as a [Moderator candidate at ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/4) @2013  (Unfortunately I didn't get a chance :( ) and have been contributing at ProWebmasters by editing, flagging, answering and commenting for the past 2 years so I know the difficulty in contributing consistently.
But you people have been giving your contribution in a wonderful manner. 
I hope you will do more and more as you have more privileges as a moderator. :)

Comment: Sathiya, thanks for your kind words and a priceless vote. With power comes responsibility - and I take it all seriously. Yes, I commit to be a keen moderator.